# Type roles and confusing behavior by `coerce`

Tags: haskell, roles, coerce

I have a type `Id a` and I'm trying to prevent accidentally coercing, e.g., an `Id Double` to an `Id Int`.

If I understand type roles correctly, the following should not compile.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RoleAnnotations #-}
import Data.Coerce (coerce)

type role Id nominal
newtype Id a = Id String

badKey :: Id Int
badKey = coerce (Id "I point to a Double" :: Id Double)
```

Unfortunately, it does:

```
Prelude> :load Id.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Id.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> :type badKey
badKey :: Id Int
```

What am I missing about type roles?

Comment: `a` in `Id` is a phantom variable and has no impact on the actual value inside. If you had `newtype Id a = Id a`, then coercion would have failed.

Comment: @lehins The point of the `type role` was to make that not be the case. This question is asking why that didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Coercible`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.12/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/GHC-Types.html#t:Coercible) has three possible "types" of instances (which are automagically generated by the compiler, not defined by the user). Only *one* of them is actually affected by [roles](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=roles#roles).

- Every type is coercible to itself.
- You can coerce "under" a type constructor, provided the affected type variables are `representational` or `phantom`. For example, you can coerce a `Map Char Int` into a `Map Char (Data.Monoid.Sum Int)` because for [`Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#t:Map) we have `type role Map nominal representational`.
- You can *always* coerce a newtype to the underlying type and vice versa, provided the newtype constructor is in scope. This ignores all roles! The rationale is that, given that the constructor is available, you could always wrap and unwrap manually, so the role doesn't give you any safety anyway.

In your example, the third rule applies. Had the newtype been defined in another module and the constructor not imported, the coercion would have failed (to make it work again, you would need to switch the role to `phantom`).

The somewhat surprising special behaviour for newtypes is explained in [this](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/13598) GHC issue.